# fedorqui, nuevo moderador

Tags: discusión

Desde esta semana soy moderador de este sitio, a propuesta del equipo de Community Managers de Stack Exchange. Como estamos aún en fase Beta, soy un moderator [Pro Tempore](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) y [me uno](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) a [Flimzy](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12/flimzy), [JoulSauron](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/106/joulsauron) y [Joze](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/110/joze). Más adelante, cuando [nuestros números](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language) nos califiquen para graduarnos, se celebrarán elecciones en las que moderadores serán elegidos.

Burocracia aparte, dejadme comentar que cojo con ilusión este cargo y espero que pueda ayudar al sitio. Llevo unos tres años en este sitio (y un poco más en Stack Overflow, el sitio donde soy más activo) y mis aportaciones han sido generalmente en forma de preguntas.

Soy hablante de castellano nativo y hay muchas cosas que me suenan bien, pero necesito tiempo e investigación para explicar bien, así que no respondo tantas preguntas como querría. Del mismo modo, soy consciente de que a veces escribo o hablo mal, ya sea por error o por tener algún concepto confuso; por tanto, ¡comentádmelo! Vuestros comentarios al respecto me ayudan a perfeccionar mi propia lengua y eso es lo que más me gusta.

Sigo con interés la pestaña de [Unanswered](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/unanswered), pues creo positivo que toda buena pregunta tenga una buena respuesta. Por ello, me gusta ofrecer recompensas de vez en cuando para ir "limpiando" esa lista.

También me gusta utilizar el botón de "editar" para mejorar el aspecto de las aportaciones de otros usuarios, así como comentar para sugerir mejoras a los nuevos usuarios e para intentar promover buena calidad y claridad.

Mi idea es seguir haciendo básicamente lo mismo como moderador, utilizando las nuevas herramientas de las que dispondré para hacerlo las cosas de una forma más sistemática.

Además, me gustará repasar todo lo que se ha comentado hasta la fecha en el Meta para cotejar si hay debates que deben replantearse, clarificar decisiones comunes y, en general, conseguir que el sitio tenga unas líneas generales lo suficientemente claras para que podamos preguntar y contestar con tranquilidad, así como digerir a los nuevos usuarios de forma agradable.

También creo que sería bueno potenciar el sitio para incrementar el número de usuarios y la cantidad de preguntas, pues parece ser el tema que llevamos más cojo últimamente. Hay muchos sitios para exponer dudas sobre el castellano en internet, sí, ¿pero no sería bonito que este se convirtiera en uno de los referentes, tal y como ha conseguido Stack Overflow en el mundo de la programación?

He estado investigando todas las herramientas que están a disposición de los moderadores, que son muchas, pero no pude encontrar ninguna que sirva para comunicarse privadamente con los otros moderadores. Por tanto, permitidme utilizar estas últimas líneas para saludar a Flimzy, JoelSauron y Joze y agradecerles el enorme esfuerzo que ponen en mantener el sitio tan sano y limpio. ¡Espero seguir aprendiendo mucho de vosotros, ahora trabajando codo con codo con vosotros!

¡Muchas gracias por leer hasta aquí y espero seros de utilidad!

Comment: Bienvenido, y gracias!

Comment: ¡Gracias! Respecto a hablar con nosotros en privado, acabo de crear un nuevo chat room para que podamos hablar: [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39376/spanish-lu-moderators) Todas me parecen buenas iniciativas. Tenemos que decidir las mejores maneras de implementarlas.

Comment: @Joze fantástica idea. ¡Nos "vemos" allí!

Comment: @Flimzy ¡gracias a ti! Hablemos en el futuro en el chat que acaba de crear Joze.

Comment: Enhorabuena, fedorqui.

Comment: @Jdamian muchas gracias : )

Comment: Felicitaciones @fedorqui !!.

Comment: @DGaleano ¡¡gracias!!