# Histórico de moderadores de Spanish.SE / Timeline of Spanish.SE moderators

Tags: discusión, moderadores

Durante el tiempo, Spanish.SE ha tenido distintos moderadores. Unos fueron elegidos inicialmente, luego salieron y fueron cubiertos por otros.

¿Cuál ha sido la evolución de moderadores en este sitio?

Comment: Idea tomada de [Timeline of Parenting moderators](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1251/14546).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

| Fecha | Anuncio | Moderadores |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 dic 2011 | [Moderator Pro-Tem Announcement](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/127/1674) |  |
|  | ✅ Entra [Gonzalo Medina](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/157/gonzalo-medina) | [image] |
|  | ✅ Entra [Flimzy](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12/flimzy) | [image] |
|  | ✅ Entra [Joze](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/110/joze) | [image] |
| 15 feb 2012 | ❌ Sale Gonzalo Medina |  |
| 9 jul 2012 | ✅ Entra [JoulSauron](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/106/joulsauron) | [image] |
| 2 may 2016 | ✅ Entra [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1674/fedorqui) - [fedorqui, nuevo moderador](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2478/1674) | [image] |
|  | ❌ Sale JoulSauron |  |
| 3 mar 2017 | ✅ Entra [Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/5481/diego) | [image] |
| 31 Jul 2019 | ❌ Sale Flimzy -https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3124/1674 |  |
| 19 Ago 2019 | ❌ Sale Joze - [Stepping down as moderator - Renunciando como moderador (Joze)](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3140/1674) |  |
| 17 sep 2019 | [Elecciones Pro Tem](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/1) | [2019 Community Moderator Election Results](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3181/1674) |
|  | ✅ Entra [Charlie](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie) - [Presentación como moderador](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3190/1674) | [image] |
| 14 oct 2019 | ❌ Sale Diego - [Stepping down as moderator - Renunciando como moderador (Diego)](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3221) |  |
| 15 nov 2019 | ❌ Sale fedorqui - [This is it! Gracias por todo. Renuncio al cargo de moderador (fedorqui)](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3241) |  |
| 19 oct 2020 | [Elecciones a moderador](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/2) | [Resultados](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4397/12637) |
|  | ✅ Entra [wimi](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/24236/wimi?tab=profile) - [Presentación como moderador](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4398/12637) | [image: wimi] |
|  | ✅ Entra [Glorfindel](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/13538/glorfindel?tab=profile) | [image: Glorfindel] |
| 28 jun 2022 | [Elecciones a moderador](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/3) | [Resultados](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4463/12637) |
|  | ✅ Entra [greuze](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/8422/greuze) | [image: greuze] |
|  | ❌ Sale Charlie - [Charlie renuncia a su puesto de moderador](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4457) |  |

---

Viendo el equipo completo cada vez.

#### 8 dic 2011. [Moderator Pro-Tem Announcement](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/127/1674)

- Entra [Gonzalo Medina](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/157/gonzalo-medina)
- Entra [Flimzy](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12/flimzy)
- Entra [Joze](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/110/joze)

Equipo completo:

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### 15 feb 2012

- Sale Gonzalo Medina

Equipo completo:

[image]
[image]

#### 9 jul 2012

- Entra [JoulSauron](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/106/joulsauron)

Equipo completo:

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### 2 may 2016

- Entra [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1674/fedorqui)  <sub>[fedorqui, nuevo moderador](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2478/1674)</sub>

Equipo completo:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### 3 mar 2017

- Entra [Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/5481/diego)
- Sale JoulSauron

Equipo completo:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### 17 sep 2019. [Elecciones Pro Tem](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/1) → [2019 Community Moderator Election Results](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3181/1674)

- Entra [Charlie](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie)  <sub>[Presentación como moderador](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3190/1674)</sub>
- Sale Flimzy  <sub>[Stepping down as moderator (Flimzy)](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3124/1674)</sub>
- Sale Joze  <sub>[Stepping down as moderator - Renunciando como moderador (Joze)](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3140/1674)</sub>

Equipo completo:

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### 14 oct 2019

- Sale Diego  <sub>[Stepping down as moderator - Renunciando como moderador (Diego)](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3221)</sub>

Equipo completo:

[image]
[image]

#### 15 nov 2019

- Sale fedorqui  <sub>[This is it! Gracias por todo. Renuncio al cargo de moderador (fedorqui)](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3241)</sub>

Equipo completo:

[image]

#### 19 oct 2020. [Elecciones a moderador](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/2) → [Resultados](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4397/12637)

- Entra [wimi](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/24236/wimi?tab=profile) <sub>[Presentación como moderador](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4398/12637)</sub>
- Entra [Glorfindel](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/13538/glorfindel?tab=profile)

Equipo completo:

[image] [image: wimi] [image: Glorfindel]

#### 28 jun 2022. [Elecciones a moderador](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/3) → [Resultados](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4463/12637)

- Entra [greuze](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/8422/greuze)
- Sale Charlie <sub>[Charlie renuncia a su puesto de moderador](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4457)</sub>

Equipo completo:

[image: wimi] [image: Glorfindel] [image: greuze]

Comment: Es curioso el uso de entra y sale. Lo tradicional sería decir sale (cuando empieza) y vase (cuando termina), ¿no? No sé, solo que me parecía raro decir sale al concluir el mando y no al tomar pose de él.

Comment: @user0721090601 ¿sale _al_ campo o sale _del_ campo? :D Yo pensé en la segunda opción, viéndolo como entrar/salir del equipo de moderadores.