# Presentación como moderador

Tags: discusión, moderadores

¡Buenas a todos!

Llevo unos días pensando en hacer esta introducción, disculpadme si he tardado un poco, simplemente quería dejar pasar un poco de tiempo desde el resultado de las elecciones dado el final un poco alocado que tuvieron con su cancelación anticipada y demás.

Me gustaría en primer lugar agradecer a todos aquellos que me han estado animando estas semanas pasadas a que me presentara como candidato. Como moderador confío estar a la altura de lo que se espera de mí. El caso es que de repente se ha abierto ante mí un océano de posibilidades nuevas, algunas de las cuales dan miedo solo de verlas. Jamás en la vida había sentido tan cierta la frase aquella de "un gran poder conlleva una gran responsabilidad". Digo esto porque seguramente tardaré un tiempo en ponerme a la altura de los moderadores ya existentes. Ellos me llevan años de ventaja (literalmente) pero sé que me van a ayudar a sacar de mí lo mejor.

Simplemente recordaros que usaré el poder que se me ha confiado por el bien de la comunidad, y que soy un humilde servidor de ustedes. Va siendo hora de hacer por todos lo que otros han hecho por mí. No dudéis en contactar conmigo (o con el moderador con el que tengáis más confianza) para cualquier asunto que queráis tratar. Tenéis incluso una dirección de correo en [mi descripción de usuario](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie?tab=profile) por si necesitáis un canal más privado.

**¡Al turrón!**

Comment: ¡Bienvenido y muchas gracias por presentarte! Ya has demostrado como usuario un gran talante, seguro que será igual como moderador. Aquí estaremos para lo que haga falta.

Comment: Gracias a ti por presentarte! Al final es más trabajo y responsabilidad, el favor nos lo haces tú a nosotros y no al revés. Confiamos en ti pero tampoco te sientas presionado, con el tiempo le pillarás el tranquillo y serás un gran mod.

Comment: Bravo, Charlie.  Me da mucho gusto que hayas aceptado el papel de moderador.  No dudes de avisar a la comunidad cuando veas algo que podemos hacer para apoyar al equipo moderador.