# 2020 Moderator Elections — Community Interest Check / ¿Alguien interesado en presentarse?

Tags: discusión, moderación, elecciones, moderadores

*English version below (corrections are welcome)*

---

¡Buenas, peña!

Me comunican desde arriba que en un corto espacio de tiempo este sitio tendrá sus primeras elecciones reales y completas a moderador, como corresponde a los sitios que han perdido su estatus de *beta*. Podéis leer cómo funcionan estas elecciones (y los requisitos que hacen falta para presentarse) [aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/350184).

El objetivo de esta publicación es conocer el interés que tenéis en presentaros a estas elecciones, antes de que las elecciones tengan lugar. Ya os digo que yo me presentaré, por lo que en caso de que nadie más se presente al menos este sitio tendrá un moderador, aunque no me gustaría seguir solo.

Por favor, publicad una respuesta solo en el caso de que tengáis planeado presentaros como candidatos (tened en cuenta que publicar una respuesta aquí no significa que seáis ya candidatos, el tiempo de presentaros oficialmente como tales vendrá más adelante).

Os iré informando de todo lo que vaya aconteciendo al respecto.

---

Hello, people!

I've been told from above that in a short space of time this site will have their first "full" elections for moderators, as corresponds to the sites that have lost their *beta* status. You can read how these elections work (and the requirements needed to run in them) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/350184).

The purpose of this post is to gauge any interest people have in running for a moderator position in these elections before the elections actually happen. I can tell you that I'm going to run in them, so in case no one else shows up at least this site will have a moderator, although I would not like to continue alone.

Please post an answer only if you plan to present yourself as candidates (keep in mind that posting an answer here does not mean that you are already a candidate, the time to officially present yourself as such will come later).

I will keep you informed about everything that happen about this matter.

Comment: Gracias por cuidar del stack. Tus esfuerzos no pasan desapercibidos. Cuando [renuncié como moderador](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3221/5481) pensé en presentarme a estas elecciones si se arreglaban algunas de las cosas que me llevaron a tomar esa decisión (No puedo creer que hayan pasado solo 4 meses. Parece que fue hace mucho más...). Meta-post a Meta-post (de https://meta.stackexchange.com) se me fueron quitando las ganas de estar siguiera pendiente y la esperanza de que la situación mejorase. A día de hoy ya he perdido la motivación que necesitaría para dedicarme a esta tarea.

Comment: @Diego gracias a ti. Soy consciente del desánimo que se ha instalado en buena parte de los usuarios más veteranos, y lo respeto. Por mi parte, simplemente prefiero que el sitio siga adelante con un moderador (aunque no pueda dedicarle mucho tiempo) a que sea borrado por falta de moderadores.

Comment: De no haber mods, creo que los CM harían las tareas pertinentes (muy muy de mínimos, como atender flags y poco más. Es posible que la naturaleza bilingüe del stack les diese muchos problemas). Dicho esto, no veo mal que la gente quiera ser mod. Este stack necesita que la gente quiera participar y quiera hacer porque otros participen más. Espero que haya mayor participación que la última vez cuando todo el mundo decía que los candidatos obvios erais tú y Walen y nadie más se presentó aunque fuese para tener una mínima ronda de votaciones.

Comment: Veo con simpatía que vaya incorporándose nueva gente al sitio, una nueva hornada siempre trae consigo nuevas ideas que seguro que hacen mejorar el sitio. Lo que veo como un auténtico páramo es Meta, cosa que resulta bastante desalentador porque hay muchas cosas por hacer. El/los moderador/es que opten al cargo ojalá lo hagan con ideas interesantes y ganas de ponerlas en marcha, pues la simple gestión del día a día no es suficiente para que el sitio mejore. Hace falta mucho más empuje en la edición, revisión de calidad, definición de los límites del _off topic_, etc. Crucemos los dedos.

Comment: Pienso que es una muy buena noticia. Por mi experiencia propia como moderadora en otro sitio SE, creo que es muy importante que haya como mínimo 3 moderadores, incluso en los sitios más pequeños y con menos actividad (y este no lo es tanto). De vez en cuando hemos tenido ciertos "líos" que creo no habría sabido gestionar yo sola. Pues bueno, a ver si se anima alguien. (Y esto también quiere decir que habría que felicitar a Charlie por su labor).

Comment: Que conste que el comentario anterior lo he escrito pensando en animar a ofrecerse voluntariamente a todos aquellos usuarios a los que les gusta este sitio web y no han sido nunca moderadores (los que ya lo han sido saben perfectamente a qué me refiero). Además, os puedo asegurar que es una experiencia muy interesante, por lo menos lo ha sido para mí: he aprendido muchísimo italiano, un poco de inglés y muchas cosas más que nunca hubiera imaginado que aprendería aquí (es difícil explicarlo, pero lo más increíble es que siento que he crecido como persona).

Comment: Bueno, nada, que puede que algún día se vaya a la porra todo esto (ojalá no sea así, a pesar de las "nubes negras" que todos hemos visto), pero yo siento que he ganado mucho.

Comment: @Charo absolutamente, es una tarea complicada, compleja pero también muy humanizante y pedagógica para uno mismo. Yo lo fui con mucho placer, pero las decisiones de Stack Exchange en los últimos meses superaron el nivel de lo que pienso que es aceptable. Por ello, actualmente no considero que merezcan que use mi tiempo personal para gestionar su plataforma y tomar decisiones por ellos.

Comment: `"If the number of nominees is less than or equal to the number of moderator slots the election will add, this phase will be extended by another seven days. If this is still the case once the extended period is over, the election will either be cancelled entirely (on graduated sites) or the nominee(s) will be made pro-tem moderators (on beta sites)."`  How many moderator positions are available? Since we are no longer a Beta site, if we get ≤ this many candidates, will we have no moderators?

Comment: @ukemi we are not still in an election process, we were just checking how many people have interest in running in an election. Given that nobody has shown interest the election has been postponed a couple of months, then we will check again. Until then I'll continue being the moderator of the site.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Hola a todos - I'd like to declare my interest in running for moderator. I love this site, and while I sympathise completely with many of the old guard not wishing to donate their time and effort in an environment where they no longer feel comfortable or supported, I want to see Spanish SE as a resource and community continue to grow, and take an active part in this.

Comment: I am sure you can be a great moderator! Thanks for devoting so much time to the site and providing so much quality on your posts.

Comment: Good news, ukemi. I totally agree with @fedorqui'SOstopharming' and I can assure you it's a very interesting experience, specially when it's possible to work in group with other moderators.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been talking with the CM in charge of this site and I've been told that we need at least four candidates (including me) to have a competitive election (there's 3 positions to fill). Let's see if someone else volunteers.

Comment: Hey there! Know it's been a while since this interest check was posted, but just popping by to highlight that the election is currently underway, and that [we need more candidates](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4391/8740) in case you're still up for it ^_^